# Jest (unable to set unique href for window.parent.location.href)

Tags: javascript, jestjs, jsdom

I have in my code a check to see if a page is being loaded inside iframe.

App.js

```js
if (window.location !== window.parent.location) {
  console.log('App is running inside iframe!');
}
```

Jest test...

App.spec.js

```js
delete window.location
window.location = new URL(`https://some-fake-url`)

delete window.parent.location
window.parent.location = new URL(`https://parent-fake-url`);
```

Inside the Jest test both `window.location.href` and `window.parent.location.href` are both set with the same value.

How can I set each to be unique?

Answer (score 1):

I believe I was able to resolve this with the following...

```js
    global.window = Object.create(window);
    delete global.window.parent;
    global.window.parent = Object.create(window);

    Object.defineProperty(global.window, 'location', {
        value: {
          href: 'https://my-site'
        }
    });

    Object.defineProperty(global.window.parent, 'location', {
        value: {
          href: 'https://my-parent-site'
        }
    });
```

Comment: While this might work on one test, any subsequent tests that rely on these properties being the same will fail, unless these are all redefined.  Can't a mock be used instead?

Comment: works here! I'm also setting `global.window` back to the original value like this
```const previous = {...global.window}
...
...
const global.window = previous```

Answer (score 0):

This also works if you want to use the URL api:

```
global.window = Object.create(window);
delete global.window.parent;
global.window.parent = Object.create(window);

window.location = new URL('https://my-site');
window.parent.location = new URL('https://my-parent-site');
```